# Fedora 37 with GNOME 43 - adjust Files/Nautilus sidebar width

Tags: gnome, nautilus, dconf

It seems that GNOME 43 removed the ability to adjust the width of the left sidebar in Nautilus (named Files now, apparently?) by dragging the border. Does anyone know a workaround for this? I'd like to make it wider than the default. The `org.gnome.nautilus.window-state.sidebar-width` property in `dconf` doesn't do anything anymore, it's mentioned in [this old answer from 2013](https://askubuntu.com/a/258138). I also checked out `org.gnome.file-roller.ui.sidebar-width` in `dconf`, but that key also appears to be unused.

For these two keys, Dconf Editor shows the message:

"*No schema available. A schema is what describes the use of a key, and Dconf Editor can't find one associated with this key. If the application that was using this key has been uninstalled, or if this key is obsolete, you may want to erase it.*"

This implies to me that the sidebar width used to be adjustable through `dconf` but not longer is and the keys (or at least `org.gnome.nautilus.window-state.sidebar-width`) still exist but aren't used anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue thread posted on the Gnome file repo, see
[Sidebar too wide, doesn't reflect sidebar items width](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/2456).
The options you mentioned are no longer available, which is confirmed in the issue thread.

IMHO, there are 2 workarounds so far,

1. compile the un-merged version e.g. [Draft: ui: Use AdwAdaptiveState to manage adaptive UI](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/merge_requests/1009)
2. rollback to gnome file version 42

Answer (score 0):

Nautilus/Files sidebar width size in Gnome can be changed with `org.gnome.nautilus.window-state.sidebar-width` through `dconf`.

Comment: Sorry, `org.gnome.nautilus.window-state.sidebar-width` is the key that I've found doesn't do anything. Typo on my part, I've edited to question to be more clear. Have you tried using this method with GNOME 43 specifically, by chance?